# Creating XML from MarkUp HTML

Tags: c#, html, xml

I've got a few web pages that have static data in HTML mark-up tables. By this, I mean, manually maintained text:

```
<table border="1" >
<tr><th>Number</th><th>Date</th><th>BW</th><th>WW</th><th>%</th><th>Type</th><th>CED</th><th>BW</th><th>WW</th><th>YW</th><th>Mlk</th><th>Me</th></tr>
<tr><td>313</td><td>9/16/2013</td><td>74</td><td>512</td><td>100</td><td>861U</td><td>3</td><td>-1.1</td><td>54</td><td>85</td><td>16</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>315</td><td>10/6/2013</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>W179</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
<tr><td>316</td><td>10/102013</td><td>72</td><td>595</td><td>94.2</td><td>W179</td><td>7</td><td>-2.3</td><td>53</td><td>80</td><td>21</td><td>-3</td></tr>
<tr><td>350</td><td>10/11/2013</td><td>71</td><td>703</td><td>100</td><td>W179</td><td>7</td><td>-2.3</td><td>46</td><td>72</td><td>20</td><td>-5</td></tr>
<tr><td>392</td><td>3/8/2013</td><td>61</td><td>651</td><td>100</td><td>RANGER</td><td>7</td><td>-2.3</td><td>52</td><td>82</td><td>20</td><td>-2</td></tr>
<tr><td>303</td><td>7/3/2013</td><td>63</td><td>-</td><td>97.1</td><td>W179</td><td>8</td><td>-3.2</td><td>N/A</td><td>82</td><td>21</td><td>-8</td></tr>
<tr><td>304</td><td>7/8/2013</td><td>62</td><td>-</td><td>97.1</td><td>W179</td><td>7</td><td>-3.9</td><td>N/A</td><td>69</td><td>20</td><td>-4</td></tr>
<tr><td>397</td><td>3/18/2013</td><td>78</td><td>621</td><td>100</td><td>STATEMENT</td><td>6</td><td>-2.7</td><td>55</td><td>84</td><td>19</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>395</td><td>3/17/2013</td><td>63</td><td>716</td><td>94.2</td><td>STATEMENT</td><td>5</td><td>-2.7</td><td>54</td><td>85</td><td>19</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>390</td><td>3/6/2013</td><td>66</td><td>583</td><td>94.2</td><td>ENVY</td><td>2</td><td>-0.6</td><td>55</td><td>80</td><td>23</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>388</td><td>3/4/2013</td><td>53</td><td>621</td><td>100</td><td>STATEMENT</td><td>10</td><td>-5.1</td><td>49</td><td>82</td><td>20</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>300</td><td>3/22/2013</td><td>61</td><td>633</td><td>100</td><td>RANGER</td><td>8</td><td>-2.8</td><td>49</td><td>81</td><td>19</td><td>-2</td></tr>
<tr><td>379</td><td>2/1/2013</td><td>55</td><td>518</td><td>100</td><td>STATEMENT</td><td>8</td><td>-4.1</td><td>61</td><td>98</td><td>18</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>398</td><td>3/20/2013</td><td>62</td><td>664</td><td>100</td><td>RANGER</td><td>6</td><td>-2.3</td><td>53</td><td>83</td><td>20</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>384</td><td>2/10/2013</td><td>61</td><td>650</td><td>100</td><td>ENVY</td><td>3</td><td>-1</td><td>50</td><td>70</td><td>19</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>369</td><td>1/30/2013</td><td>76</td><td>651</td><td>100</td><td>STATEMENT</td><td>5</td><td>-2.4</td><td>60</td><td>99</td><td>20</td><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>373</td><td>1/21/2013</td><td>71</td><td>433</td><td>100</td><td>STATEMENT</td><td>4</td><td>-1.6</td><td>55</td><td>89</td><td>17</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>393</td><td>3/10/2013</td><td>63</td><td>717</td><td>100</td><td>STATEMENT</td><td>3</td><td>-4.6</td><td>51</td><td>91</td><td>20</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>389</td><td>3/8/2013</td><td>72</td><td>723</td><td>88.3</td><td>ENVY</td><td>4</td><td>-0.6</td><td>54</td><td>76</td><td>24</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>364</td><td>10/1/2012</td><td>60</td><td>574</td><td>100</td><td>RANGER</td><td>1</td><td>0.4</td><td>56</td><td>84</td><td>21</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Currently, I am contemplating using a `WebClient.DownloadString` to pull all of the text in, and try to create an XML file out of it by parsing each row `<tr>`.

That sounds tedious, and I would rather not reinvent the wheel. Besides, a few good solutions would give me something to look at for ideas on how to best approach writing my version.

Has anyone come across some code that can do this?

I've started, to give you an idea of what I'm working on:

```
    private const string XML_DATA = "App_Data/page_data.xml";
    private const string TABLE_START = "<table>";
    private const string TABLE_STOP = "</table>";
    private string[] TABLE_ROW = { "<tr>", "</tr>" };
    private string[] TABLE_HEAD = { "<th>", "</th>" };
    private string[] TABLE_DET = { "<td>", "</td>" };

    private void load_data() {
        if (!File.Exists(XML_DATA)) {
            string HtmlText;
            using (var client = new WebClient()) {
                HtmlText = client.DownloadString(Server.MapPath("/Sales.aspx"));
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(HtmlText)) {
                var lcTxt = HtmlText.ToLower();
                int len0 = TABLE_START.Length;
                int tStart = lcTxt.IndexOf(TABLE_START) + len0;
                int tStop = lcTxt.IndexOf(TABLE_STOP);
                if ((len0 < tStart) && (tStart < tStop)) {
                    var tableString = HtmlText.Substring(tStart, tStop - tStart);
                    var tableRows = tableString.Split(TABLE_ROW, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    foreach (var row in tableRows) {
                        if (-1 < row.IndexOf(TABLE_HEAD[0])) {
                          //
                        } else {
                          //
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course, you can see that is already going to fail, because the Markup using `<table border="1">`.

Yes, easy to fix, but I'd rather have a working guide that has already been through a lot of debugging steps.

**UPDATE:** I tried using [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlDocument.aspx)'s [LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) method, but it can't seem to read basic HTML:

[image: html error]

Answer (score 1):

You definitely shouldn't be trying to parse that manually. Other people have already solved that problem.

If your markup is valid XML (and from what you've shown us, it looks like it is), then you can just parse it as XML:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(HtmlString);
doc.Save("myfile.xml");
```

But for that matter, if it's already valid XML markup, and all you need to do is save it as a file, then you don't need to parse it. Just save it:

```
File.WriteAllText("myfile.xml", HtmlString);
```

Comment: +1. The HTML is not **just** that table info. Will that code bomb if there are other fields, or is it intelligent enough to figure it out?

Comment: The issue is not whether it has other fields, but whether the markup is valid as XML. For example, the following will not parse successfully: `<div height=30>nnn</div>` (no quotes around the 30), `<br>` (no closing slash) `&nbsp;` (nbsp is not pre-defined in XML). If you think there might be things like that, you should consider using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which is designed for parsing HTML.

Comment: Rats. It was too easy. That gave me an **XmlException** `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.` This is a page built using a Master Page, so Line 1, position 1 starts with `<%@ Page Title=...`.

Comment: ASP.NET syntax is neither valid XML nor valid HTML. You could try first stripping out all the ASP.NET stuff before you do your parsing: `HtmlString = Regex.Replace(HtmlString, "<%(.*?)%>", "");